# onkeyup instead of on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JTube found over here: [JTube at github](https://github.com/monkeecreate/jTube/blob/master/examples/other/search/index.html)

I'm trying to make a request on keyup instead of on submit. This is the script:

```
 var qsParm = new Array();
    function qs() {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var parms = query.split('&');
        for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
            var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
            if (pos > 0) {
                var key = parms[i].substring(0,pos);
                var val = parms[i].substring(pos+1);
                qsParm[key] = val;
            }
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        qs();

        if(qsParm['search'] == '' || qsParm['search'] == null || qsParm['search'] == undefined)
            qsParm['search'] = 'splinter cell';
        else
            qsParm['search'] = unescape(qsParm['search']);

        $('input[name=search]').val(qsParm['search']);

        $.jTube({
            request: 'search',
            requestValue: qsParm['search'],
            limit: 10,
            page: 1,
            success: function(videos) {
                $(videos).each(function() {
                    $('#example').append('<li><a href="'+this.link+'"><img src="'+this.thumbnail+'"><br>'+this.title+'</a> - '+this.length+'</li>');
                });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $('#example').html(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

As far as I understand the function is ''qs'' So therefore I tried:

```
$("input").onkeyup(function(){
     qs();
     return false;         
 });
```

Did not work. I tried many other things with no success. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the "sendQS" function (which is anonymous in your example) to actually send the data.  Also, the jquery function is `keyup` not `onkeyup`.

```
function sendQS() {
    qs();

    if(qsParm['search'] == '' || qsParm['search'] == null || qsParm['search'] == undefined)
        qsParm['search'] = 'splinter cell';
    else
...
}

$("input").keyup(function(e){
     sendQS();
     return false;         
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
     qs();
     return false;         
 });
```

jQuery version of `onKeyup` is called `keyup`. In general `onXXX` are the DOM events and jQuery handlers simply do not have `on` in them.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
  $('#target').keyup(function() {
  alert('Handler for .keyup() called.');
});
```